# Is it possible to display previous PowerPoint slide on secondary monitor?

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

One of our lecturers is trying to set up his PC so that after he advances a slide the previous one will display on our other projector.

Is this possible with PowerPoint? If not, are there any alternatives to complete such task?

Or will a custom script have to be written to do something such as screenshot and display that on the other monitor (I noticed it is possible to write Visual Basic macros for PowerPoint, but I don't know much VB)?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with PowerPoint as it comes out of the box, but Chirag Dalal has done some interesting work on making it do the impossible:

http://officeone.mvps.org/